# Embed mysql variables in string

Tags: mysql

This is the table that I have. Effective date is a user input, then I need to use a trigger that produces Print depending on the language the user inputs (English or French only).

For English, I used DATE_FORMAT to achieve the output as shown, but for French I created another table with all the french months which I then use to fetch the month I need.

However, I'm having trouble producing a string using these 3 variables to create the final date.

Main Table:

```
╔══════════╤════════════════╤═════════════╗
║ Language │ Effective Date │ Print       ║
╠══════════╪════════════════╪═════════════╣
║ English  │ 23/05/2016     │ 23 May 2016 ║
╟──────────┼────────────────┼─────────────╢
║ French   │ 23/05/2016     │             ║
╚══════════╧════════════════╧═════════════╝
```

French Months Table:

```
╒═════╤═════════╕
│ num │ Month   │
╞═════╪═════════╡
│ 1   │ Janvier │
├─────┼─────────┤
│ 2   │ Fevrier │
├─────┼─────────┤
│ 3   │ Mars    │
╘═════╧═════════╛
and so on...
```

Trigger Code:

```
BEGIN 

  IF NEW.language = "English" 
  THEN
  SET NEW.print = DATE_FORMAT(NEW.date, '%d %M %Y');
  END IF;

  IF NEW.language = "French"
  THEN
  SET @f_day = EXTRACT(DAY FROM new.date);
  SET @f_month = (SELECT month FROM `french_month` WHERE num = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM NEW.date));
  SET @f_year = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM new.date);
  SET NEW.print = @f_day @f_month @f_year; //I just need to display these 3 variables together 
  END IF; 

END
```

Comment: as with anything in mysql, if you're concatenating strings, you need to use [concat()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

Comment: You really don't want to do this in MySQL. There are fantastic locale libraries for most programming languages that can handle localization issues like this and more. MySQL barely has any support at all and adding it will be an extremely painful process.

Comment: @MarcB Oh man, I completely forgot about that, thanks.

Comment: @tadman I realised that, but I have no idea how to deal with locales, can you point me to documentation on that matter or anything to get me started, thanks.

Comment: It depends entirely on what language you're using external to MySQL. Many have robust add-on packages that make this sort of thing very flexible. Some countries lack a singular standard for dates, times, and numbers, so you need to be adaptable. Canada, as an example, probably has three commonly used date formats depending on the context or if it's French or English. Most operating systems have sane defaults but still allow you to over-ride this.

Comment: @ybce I like what the boys at teletext.io have done (sorry offtopic)